# PHP shuffle an array and remember

Tags: php, cookies, shuffle

I want php to shuffle an array for user once, and then remember it through cookie so that on the refresh, array won't be shuffled again if cookie is set. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried storing it somewhere? Like the cookie, session, a file or database?

Comment: `$arr = array(3,5,6,1); $arr = array_shuffle($arr); setcookie('wa', serialize($arr));`

Comment: why have you "unaccept" the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle) for shuffeling and [save](http://php.net/set_cookie) your array in a cookie ([serialize](http://php.net/serialize)).
Every page reload you [check if the cookie exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php), if yes read it and if not shuffle your data and save it..

Comment: Thanks, helped me. I stored using serialize, and gzcompress. But it stores whole array in cookie, is there any other option like saving only array key and randomizing an array by it?